# Why does WP care about main?

Tags: frama-c

In the following minimal example (slightly altered from Allan Blanchard's excellent tutorial -- section 3.2.3.3 Side Effects):

```
int h = 42;

/*@
  requires \valid(a) && \valid(b);
  requires \valid_read(a) && \valid_read(b);
  ensures *a == \old(*b) && *b == \old(*a);
 */
void swap( int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

//int test_swap(void) {
int main(void) {
    int a = 37;
    int b = 91;

    //@ assert h == 42;
    swap(&a, &b);
    //@ assert h == 42;
  return 0;
}
```

With this code as is above, WP is able to prove the first `//@ assert h == 42;` in main as expected from the discussion in the tutorial.

***IF*** the function `main` is renamed `test_swap` WP is ***un-able*** to prove the first `//@ assert h == 42;`

**Why?**

I can understand why EVA cares about the presence of `main`, but I can not understand why WP should even care, as I am only asking WP to prove the single function `main` (in one case) and `test_swap` (in the other case).

---

I am using Frama-C version: *25.0-beta (Manganese)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Frama-C indeed assumes (at kernel level) that the `main` function is the entry point of the program. That means that WP can make some assumptions about the global context (basically the initial values of global variables), but also that we might have additional verification to perform on the function. For example, here, we could write:

```c
//@ requires 0 <= h <= 100 ;
int main(void) {
  ...
}
```

In such a case, WP generates a VC for the `requires` of the `main` function and proves it:

[image]

If one really wants a behavior where the `main` function is just handled as any other function, the Frama-C kernel must be parameterized with the `-lib-entry` option. In such a case:

- WP does not try to prove the `requires` of `main`,
- WP cannot prove that `h` is 42 in the first `assert`.

```
frama-c-gui b.c -lib-entry -wp
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Your comment about WP creating VCs, *attached to `main`*, for all global variables, clearly answers my question. The point for me is I can use any old function IF I do not care about the state of global variables.